# Git repositories are all linked

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, git-bash, git-push

When I tried using the git push command from VSC terminal to push a particular directory all the directories in my VSC got into the repository. It looks like all my project folders are linked in a way and thus using git push is causing this issue.

How can this be resolved?

Comment: May you share the text output of the git push command? (Please edit the question, don’t post a comment)

Comment: What does running `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` in the repository print?  Does it print the root of the repository as you expect it?

Answer (score 0):

If your particular repository is not its own git repository (with a `.git/` subfolder in it), then Git, on `git push`, will look for the top directory (the parent folder with a `.git/` subfolder in it)

That is then the all tree which is pushed/updated, not just one folder.